# How to remove list elements given set of indexes?

Tags: python

Is there an efficient way to solve the following problem:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
indexes_to_remove = [0,2,4]

#result
lst = [2,4]
```

My solution

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
indexes_to_remove = [0,2,4]

x = -1
for i in range(len(indexes_to_remove)):
    x+=1
    if i!=0:
        indexes_to_remove[i] = indexes_to_remove[i] - x # because indexes will shift
    lst.remove(lst[indexes_to_remove[i]])
```

Comment: the best way to solve this kind of stuff is to just create a new list instead with just the items you want to keep

Comment: `[el for i, el in enumerate(lst) if i not in indexes_to_remove]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
indexes_to_remove = [0,2,4]

lst = [item for i, item in enumerate(lst) if i not in indexes_to_remove]

print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
[2, 4]
```

Comment: You solution creates a new list, question was how to remove elements from existing list. If a list is huge your approach wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [67]: lst = [1,2,3,4,5]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [68]: indexes_to_remove = [0,2,4]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [69]: for i in sorted(indexes_to_remove, reverse=True): lst.pop(i)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [70]: lst                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[70]: [2, 4]
```

Comment: You should sort `indexes_to_remove` to ensure that indices `indexes_to_remove[::-1]` are in descending order.

Comment: Indeed it is safer to reverse sort here to ensure the indices are in descending order @niekas

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove certain items from `lst` based on a list of indices `indexes_to_remove`, what you can do is sort the elements in `indexes_to_remove` in reverse order, and then remove them from `lst` in a for loop, ensuring in this way that each new index to remove is lower than the previous and hence the change in size of the list won't affect the new items to remove:

```
for i in sorted(indexes_to_remove, reverse=True):
    del lst[i]
```

**Output**

```
[2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If speed is of concern, use [`delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) function from `numpy` module:

```
import numpy as np

lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
indexes_to_remove = [0,2,4]

lst = np.array(lst)
indexes_to_remove = np.array(indexes_to_remove)

lst = np.delete(lst, indexes_to_remove)
```

Timing test for `lst = list(range(10000))` and `indexes_to_remove = list(range(0, 2000, 2))` shows `numpy.delete` is about 1000X faster than list comprehension.